# How to send a email(pdf visualforce page) to particular user on clicking the custom button?

Tags: visualforce, email, custom-button, attachment, pdf

I have made a visualforce page to generate a pdf when a custom button is clicked and I'm struggling to send the generated pdf to mail id of that particular user.I tried all the possibilities.How should I customize the code.

```
//visual force page code//
<apex:page standardController="TicketReservation__c" renderas="pdf">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@page{
    size: letter;
    margin: 10%;
    @top-center {
        content: "Invoice Date: {!MONTH(TODAY())}/{!DAY(TODAY())}/{!YEAR(TODAY())}";
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bolder;
    }
       @top-left {
        content: "INVOICE";
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
    @bottom-left {
        content: "";
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    @bottom-right {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
table {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #000000;  
}
.tablelabel {
    background: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.tableheader {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.invisiblecell {
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}
span#warningtext{
    font-size: 80%;
    background: #FFF000;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: 90px;
    align: middle;
    text-align: right;
}

</style>    
</head>

     <apex:pageBlock title="TicketDetails">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <strong>BookingNumber:{! TicketReservation__c.BookingNumber__c}</strong><br/><br/>
        <strong>Name:{! TicketReservation__c.Name}</strong><br/><br/>
        <strong>Date of journey:{! TicketReservation__c.Date_of_journey__c }</strong><br/><br/>
        <strong>From:{! TicketReservation__c.From__c }</strong><br/><br/>
        <strong>To:{! TicketReservation__c.To__c }</strong><br/><br/>
        <strong>Amount:{! TicketReservation__c.Amount__c }</strong><br/><br/>
        <strong>Discounted Amount:{! TicketReservation__c.Discounted_Amount__c }</strong><br/><br/>





        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: So far I can only see the definition of the visual force page. have you tried anything in terms of logic? If so, what have you tried, what were the results...?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site isn't a free-coding service, so including the logic you've worked on so far and keeping your question to a specific issue is important here. If you haven't been able to start on the Apex side of things yet, then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is where you should start. If you don't have the time to learn, then that's when you should start looking for a contractor or consultant who can.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you start by reviewing some very important documentation about generating PDFs and remove your `<apex:Pageblock>` references, replacing all of that instead with standard HTML `<Table>` markup. See **Components That Are Unsafe to Use When Rendering as PDF** section of [Component Behavior When Rendered as PDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_component_behavior.htm).

Once you do that, your PDF will be more likely to render to begin with unless there's something else about your VF markup that needs to be cleaned up.

While you're in the documentation there's a complete general solution to what you're trying to do for sending an email attachment that's a PDF in [Creating an Email Attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_sending_attachments.htm). That example does it by sending the attachment from a page that shows accounts. The general principles will be the same except you're dealing with a User instead of an Account.

Because you're sending this from a button, you'll want to get the user context and then do one of two things:

1. Add code to your button that calls an email template and attaches the PDF to it using the context user's ID for the SendTo and the PDF you've just printed as the attachment.

OR

2. Call up a custom messaging class controller that generates an email that can accept the context UserId and the PDF you've just "printed" as parameters. Have the class use the UserId as the SendTo and attach the PDF to the email.

Both are essentially the same, just different ways of thinking about how to do what you want. Using a Template is entirely optional.